# For any linearly independent vectors $x, y$, there is such a norm that $||x||_*>||y||_*$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Today I've seen in my class that:

> For any linearly independent vectors $x, y$, there is such a norm that $||x||_*>||y||_*$

Our lecturer called it *Benchmark theorem*.

I wanted to learn more about it: some non-trivial applications and so on. Yet after googling and skimming through a couple of books, I couldn't find anything including the theorem itself. It seems to me that the theorem is known under some other name or in some other form.

Any information on identifying the theorem is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can check easily that if $\|\cdot\|$ is some fixed norm and $A$ is a bijective endomorphism
$$\|v\|_* = \|Av\|$$
defines another norm. Expand $\{x,y\}$ to a basis of the space and define $A$ by
$$Ax = kx,\qquad Ay = k^{-1}y\qquad\text{for $k$ large enough};$$
$$Ab = b\qquad\text{for the other elements of the basis}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the idea of [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance):-
$$||x-y||_* = \sqrt{(x-y)^TS^{-1}(x-y)}$$ 
S is a **positive self definite symmetric** matrix, whose eigenvaluess represent scale in the direction of corresponding eigenvector.

It is an anisotropic norm. Since $x$ and $y$ are linearly independent, $x$ has a component along a direction perpendicular to $y$. By increasing the scale indefinitely along this axis, we can increase $||x||_*$ without affecting $||y||_*$. Hence we can find $S$ such that one of its eigenvector is along $y$ and increase the corresponding eigenvalue to a large number.